# BigBlueButton getMeetings from angular

Tags: angularjs, bigbluebutton

I tried to getMeetings from AngularJs, like this one:

```
.factory('videoConf', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://192.168.56.101/bigbluebutton/api/getMeetings?random=&checksum=a41da4221d093acc8b35a69de2cf0cdef443126a', {}, {
              'get': {
               method: 'JSONP',
               isArray: false,
               transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = xml2json(data, "");
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            }
```

In this case - error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I tried used method "GET":

```
'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false,
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = xml2json(data, "");
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            }
```

And in this case error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Please help - how i must doing request "getMeetings"?

Answer (score 2):

Direct AngularJs client side calls may not work(if BBB on other domain) because of same-origin policy.

Also BBB API response is not in Json(its in xml ) hence jsonp may fail.

However, you can easily get getMeetings API response by making server side call 
we tried this using PHP calls.